# Connect to wordpress database and my own mysql database at the same time

Tags: mysql, wordpress, connection

I have a site that i am building that mixes wordpress and my own designs together. Some parts will have a full wordpress page using a custom theme and others will be my php site with only parts of a post being pulled from the wordpress database. The issue i am running in to is when i connect to wordpress by including wp-blog-header.php i can't connect to my own custom MySQL database. How can i retain an active connection to both databases at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's in wp-blog-header.php, but my guess is you'll need to manage the connections to mysql more explicitly.

mysql_connect returns a resource handle, you should be able to use it once for each database and store those resource handles, using whichever one is appropriate. The database connection credentials for a wordpress site will be in wp-config.php, just plug them in as the arguments to mysql_connect.

Comment: That does not help me what so ever.